# Prove that if $\sup S = \infty$ then for every $N > 0$ there exists an element $s$ of $S$ such that $s > N$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

How would I prove this? Would I use upper bounds or lower bounds or would I do a proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

$\sup=\infty$, i.e $S$ is not upper bounded. and this means that for any $N$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $s>N$. since otherwise it is upper bounded.

more percisely if there exists $N$ s.t. $s\leq N$ for all $s\in S$ then $\sup S\leq N<\infty$. which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

"$\sup S=\infty$" means $S$ has no upper bound. That means that, for every $N$, $N$ is not an upper bound. In other words, $N$ isn't $\ge$ than everything in $S$. That is to say, there are things in $S$ bigger than $N$.

Compare that with what you wanted to prove.